# Copy a list of files contained inside a txt file into another folder

Tags: file-transfer

Do you know a freeware (for Windows 7 64) which can copy a list of files (contained in a txt file) into another folder (folder structure preserved or not) ?

Filelist.txt contents:
M:\DVD1\00\09.pdf
M:\DVD1\00\gethu4.pdf
M:\DVD1\00\djdd85.pdf
M:\DVD1\00\sdffjhgj.pdf
...etc..

Edit: GUI Required. Please please no .bat file script as I had problems with space or special characters with batch solutions I have tried.

Comment: PS: feels like a 'shopping question'. You might want to rewrite it to a slightly different answer.

Comment: Thanks. I hope it is better now ? ;)

Comment: If you're going to require a GUI, please specify it in your original question. Several people have spent time giving you valid recommendations which you're dismissing because they don't answer a requirement which you failed to specify.

Comment: Thanks but I have written since the beginning no .bat script. Apparently this is not sufficient so I have added your suggestion with pleasure. Sorry for my errors.

Comment: “Please no .bat file script as I had problems with space or special characters with batch solutions I have tried.” // “We should be careful to get out of an experience only the wisdom that is in it and stop there lest we be like the cat that sits down on a hot stove.  She will never sit down on a hot stove again and that is well but also she will never sit down on a cold one anymore.” [—Mark Twain](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/52127) // Just because you had problems with space, etc., with batch solutions that ***you*** have tried is no reason to refuse to look at ones that might be better.

Answer (score 7):

A GUI program is overkill & inefficient. Use Powershell:

```
Get-Content myfile.txt|Foreach-Object{copy-item -path $_.FullName -destination "path_to_destination"}
```

This ignores any requirement to maintain directory structure (as you didn't provide such).

Rather than say "please don't tell me the best way to do it, I had problems due to spaces", fix the root cause - learn how to handle the spaces.

Comment: Thanks. But scripting is too complex for me.

Comment: I *gave* you the script. You have asked for solutions, you have been given solutions - now you're adding stipulations because they use something you're afraid of. If you are working with Windows in anything but a pure end-user capacity, you pretty much have to learn Powershell to remain relevant over the next few years. It's not complex, spend a couple lunch hours looking at tutorials and you'll get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said no batch files, but a simple `FOR /F` command should do what you want. Type `for /?` at the command prompt.

Comment: Thanks. I had problems with space or special characters with batch solutions I have tried.

Comment: Spaces can be handled within batch (usually by just wrapping the path in quotes), but batch should have been put out to pasture years ago - Windows has much better scripting engines available now.

Comment: True, but for simple hacks it's pretty good!

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be `rsync --files-from=filelist.txt`.

Rsync is mainly used to copy from one computer to another, but copies to the same computer should also work.

Comment: Thanks but I am more a kind of GUI user.

Answer (score 0):

[XXCOPY](http://www.xxcopy.com/index.htm) might do what you want. (I haven't tried it.)

Comment: Thanks but there is no GUI with it.